# Altair show overlapping images

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I want to show overlapping images using `altair`.
Here's a demo code.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
source = pd.DataFrame([{"x": [0,0,0], "y": [0,0,0], 
                        "img": ["https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/gimp.png",
                               "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/7zip.png",
                               "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/ffox.png"]},])
chart=alt.Chart(source).mark_image(width=100,height=100,).encode(x='x',y='y',url='img')
chart
```

What I see as an output is not what I expected:

[image]

I wonder what's the issue here(?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to construct your dataframe this way:

```
source = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0,0,0], "y": [0,0,0], 
                       "img": ["https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/gimp.png",
                               "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/7zip.png",
                               "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/ffox.png"]})
```

i.e. it should have three rows rather than one row. If you do this, the chart works, and the last image appears on top of the others, as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing it out! The examples in `Altair`'s docs construct dataframes using  `pd.DataFrame.from_records` while I used `pd.DataFrame`. I should have paid attention to that. After all, that was kind of a mistake. :) Sorry for bothering you with this.